# Save formatted text into SQL .Net

Tags: .net, winforms

How to save and retreive a formatted text from a richtextbox into SQL database?

Comment: I am trying to insert a formatted text with color, font, italic etc into db. How can we Insert this and retreive with same format like color,font etc.. Thanks for your feedbak..

Answer (score 0):

U can do it something like this

```
 string queryString = 
        "INSERT INTO Users (Description) VALUES('" + RichTextBox1.Text + "')";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 Please, never tell anyone to use string concatenation to insert data in a datatable. Use Parameters.

Comment: Parameters are safer and more ideal, however, this approach is not incorrect, does work, and answers the question.  Alternative is to use a .Replace("'", "''") on the text to protect from injection.  +1 still.

Comment: Thanks Peretz and Steve.. But my requirement is not like this..I am trying to insert a formatted text with color, font, italic etc into db. How can we Insert this and retreive with same format like color,font etc..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself and want to share with you..Thanks

You can use RichTextBox1.rtf.

Insert Into Table1(Note)Values('" + RichTextBox1.rtf + "')

This will insert as formatted text. You can retreive the text with same format you edited in the UI.

Thanks all for you feedback..